# Vert.x Worker Thread Blocking

Tags: worker, vert.x

I have one vert.x Standard Verticle Basically,it parses HttpRequest and prepare JsonObject then I am sending JSONObject through eventbus. In Another Worker verticle that event get consumed and it will kick off execution(includes call to Penthao Data Integration Java API) it is blocking API.It took around 30 minutes to complete execution of ".kjb" file. But vert.x is continuously warning about Worker Thread Block so my question is what would be best practice in vert.x to tackle this scenario.
       Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: http://vertx.io/docs/vertx-core/java/#blocking_code

Answer (score 4):

According to [vertx doc](http://vertx.io/docs/vertx-core/java/#blocking_code) all blocking operations need to perform in code

```
vertx.executeBlocking(future -> {
  // Call some blocking API that takes a significant amount of time to return
  String result = someAPI.blockingMethod("hello");
  future.complete(result);
}, res -> {
  System.out.println("The result is: " + res.result());
});
```

So it's the best practice for all blocking tasks.

Answer (score 2):

You could also deploy your verticle as a worker.

This way:

```
vertx.deployVerticle(yourVerticleInstance, new DeploymentOptions().setWorker(true));
```